# Smarty создает пустые compiled файлы

Tags: php, smarty

такая проблема:
Раньше сайт стоял на линуксе, при переносе на мой локальный веб-сервер на windows смарти начал создавать пустые compiled файлы, в которых только стандартный комментарий смарти:

```
<!--?php /* Smarty version 2.6.19, created on 2019-02-20 18:28:08
     compiled from index.tpl */ ?-->
```

Версия smarty - 2.6.19
Пути к папках указаны правильно. 
С правами проблем нет, ведь это виндоус.
Я пробовал ставить Smarty_Test.class.php и делать тест, вот результат:

```
string(42) "Z:/home/svau.com/www/admin/smarty/plugins/" testing start:
template_dir is 'Z:/home/svau.com/www/template/'
real system path: Z:\home\svau.com\www\template
file perms: 0777
OK.
compile_dir is 'Z:/home/svau.com/www/admin/smarty/template-c-site/'
real system path: Z:\home\svau.com\www\admin\smarty\template-c-site
file perms: 0777
OK.
cache_dir is 'Z:/home/svau.com/www/admin/smarty/cache/'
real system path: Z:\home\svau.com\www\admin\smarty\cache
file perms: 0777
OK.
testing complete.
```

Конфиг:

```
    function mysmarty_site()
{
    global $config;
    $this->Smarty();
    $this->template_dir="$config[project_path]/template/";
    $this->compile_dir="$config[project_path]/admin/smarty/template-c-site/";
    $this->plugins_dir="$config[project_path]/admin/smarty/plugins/";
    $this->config_dir="$config[project_path]/admin/smarty/config/";
    $this->cache_dir="$config[project_path]/admin/smarty/cache/";
    $this->default_modifiers=array('escape_ss');
    $this->left_delimiter='{{';
    $this->right_delimiter='}}';
    $this->caching = true;
    $this->debugging = true;
    $this->force_compile = true;
    $this->error_reporting= E_ALL | E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_CORE_ERROR | E_USER_ERROR | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR;

    $this->test();
    die;
}
```

Я уже совсем не представляю, в чём проблема, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Дополнил конфиг смарти

Comment: проблем с правами нет, вы правы, ибо файлы то создаются. Но если например вы используете IIS, то пользователю IUSR надо давать права на запись в директории.

Comment: в качестве замечания, `$config[project_path]` после таких строк проверьте лог пхп, там будет что-то про неопределенную константу `project_path`, вы забыли завернуть эту строку кавычки. И для надежности и читаемости все же используйте скобки `"{$config['project_path']}"`

Comment: на форумах вот пишут, как вариант, что шаблоны находятся, но пхп не может их прочитать, т.к. например нет прав, или еще чего. так что проверьте лог пхп, и убедитесь что есть права на чтение самих файлов. в тесте приведены правда на директорию. и кэширование выключите